# Disable Wix Custom action on /quiet /silent

Tags: c#, custom-action, wix3.5

In a WIX custom action, is there a way to detect whether the MSI was invoked with /silent or /quiet command line switches? Basically what I want is to not execute the custom action (since it shows a form) or handle it differently if these command line switches were passed but I am unable to find this out.

Is there a way to possibly detect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Wix basically always sets the UILevel property to 2.0. It has its own property called WixBundleUILevel. Now important thing here is that prior to Wix 3.11 this WixBundleUILevel was an internal property and was not accessible to Bundle projects or MSI Custom Actions. So here is what I did

1. Defined a property in MSI called UI_LEVEL (important, make it all upper case)
2. In Bundle.wxs, right where I call MSIPackage, I set the UI_LEVEL property like so

   <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.MsiPath)">
                          <MsiProperty Name="UI_LEVEL" Value="[WixBundleUILevel]" />
                 </MsiPackage>

Then finally in the custom action I check for this property like

```
int uiLevel;
                if (int.TryParse(session["UI_LEVEL"], out uiLevel))
                {
                    if (uiLevel == 4)
                        using (var form = new WhatsNew())
                        {
                            form.ShowDialog();
                        }
                    else
                        session.Log("Skipping What's new dialogue as UI Level is not 4");

                }
                else
                {
                    session.Log("Couldnt figure out the UI level, so skipped the prompt");
                }
```

And finally

```
here are the possible values of this f**ed up property
                WixBundleUILevel              Value     Burn parameters
                BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY_FULL       4         (none)
                BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY_PASSIVE    3         /silent
                BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY_NONE       2         /quiet
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the property [UILevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/uilevel) and execute your CA based on your conditions.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but UILevel for me is always 2 irrespective of whather /quiet argument is passed or not. I also noticed some other properties such as ClientUILevel and WixBundleUILevel in the log files but my session argument has null for them constantly. Any ideas where I might be going wrong please?

Comment: @Nikhil, that's interesting that it's not changing; are you running your CA as deferred? If so, you won't have access to the database i.e. properties without injecting them manually to the session.

Comment: Hi no I am not running it as deferred. I came across a registered issue on Wix GitHub that claims that the bootstrapper overrides the UILevel property and always sets it to 2. There are no updates on what happened with that though. Here is the link https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/3789

Comment: Good to hear you resolved it. I have been using WiX v3.11.1 and have been able to access the `UILevel` property normally using the standard bootstrapper application.

Comment: Thanks Burrt. Would you mind sharing some code samples on how you were doing it? For me the use case was to access it in a Custom Action (not deferred) which was a part of the MSI installation sequence. This MSI was then a part of the bootstrapper.

Comment: I didn't do anything special, however, I am using the bootstrapper exe for installing my program. So if the exe is invoked with `-passive` or `-quiet`, I can observe the `UILevel` change accordingly in the log files. Accessing the property by `[UILevel]` works as expected when injecting the data into a deferred custom action. It appears you did the same steps but had different results?